# stretch divider image as per mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a navigation menu where I am adding a divider image, after every li
using `:after` and `:before`.

But I am not able to have it responsive as per the mobile device.

Please have a look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rekxgcq9/2/)

The image is not starting for left initially and is non responsive as per the device width.

HTML

```
<ul class="menu-nav-toggle">
    <li><a href="/pages/about">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="/pages/faq">Faqs</a></li>
    <li><a href="/pages/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="/pages/myaccount">My Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="/pages/cart">My cart</a></li>
    <li><a href="step1">Step</a></li>
    <li><a href="/pages/offers">Offers</a></li>
<ul>
```

CSS

```
   .menu-nav-toggle li:first-child:before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 5px;
      display: inline-block;
      background-position: center;
      background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/4jJVvVX.png);
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      top: 0;
      }

   .menu-nav-toggle li:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 5px;
      display: inline-block;
      background-position: center;
      background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/4jJVvVX.png);
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you expect like this.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rekxgcq9/3/

```
      .menu-nav-toggle li:first-child:before { background-position:left;}
      .menu-nav-toggle li:after{background-position:left;}
```

Comment: Yes, but as I said I want it to be responsive. i.e If you stretch and increase the size, It looks as if it is fixed there.

Check the SS [here](http://i.imgur.com/j6hyHwH.png).

Comment: Do you want diver for full screen with responsive.

Comment: exactly. Its size should increase. If you see the screenshot [here](http://i.imgur.com/At5ykz6.png).
The menu icon along with cart moves apart from this divider.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rekxgcq9/5/  divider Image width is 307px only so when view in big screen image will look stretched. If not ok with it's can try it in CSS box shadow.

Comment: what did you change in the fiddle?

Comment: i made changes two class are ** .menu-nav-toggle li:first-child:before { height: 3px; background-size:cover;}   .menu-nav-toggle li:after {
height: 3px;
background-size:cover;} **

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93470/discussion-between-suraj-and-ezhil-ui-developer).